# AWS Control Tower and KMS Keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, aws-control-tower

AWS Control Tower successfully created Security-OU and a management account. I specified KMS key while creating the landing zone.
Where is this AWS key used by control tower? I don't see it being used in Security-OU (audit and log-archive) accounts.

Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The key is used by cloud trail and config service to encrypt the data stored in s3 buckets at rest.

Please refer to below article by AWS :
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/07/aws-control-tower-provides-support-kms-encryption/